# Filtering Everything But Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this object

```js
{
  helloWorld: function () {
    console.log("Test")
  },
  debug: false,
  foo: {
    test: "test",
    bar: function () {
      console.log(false)
    }
  }
}
```

However, programmatically I want it to look like this:

```
{
  helloWorld: function() {
    console.log("Test")
  },
  foo: {
    bar: function() {
      console.log(false)
    }
  }
}
```

Basically removing everything but the functions of an object.

Comment: specific to this object? with a max nesting depth of 2? or any object with x amount of nested functions

Comment: There is no maximum depth, this object is an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a recursive call. For every key-value pairs of the object, check the value:

- if it is function, keep it
- else do a recursive call on that value

Base condition for on recursive call

- if it is not object, return null
- if the object is empty, also return null

After `map` through the key-value pairs, filter the pairs with `value` not equal null.

Finally, transform the pairs back to object

```
function keepFunc(obj) {
  if (!isObject(obj)) {
    return null
  }
  if (Object.keys(obj).length === 0) {
    return null
  }


  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([key, value]) => [
        key,
        isFunction(value) ? value : keepFunc(value)
      ])
      .filter(([key, value]) => value !== null)
  )
}
```

**Runnable example**

```js
const obj = {
  helloWorld: function() {
    console.log('Test')
  },
  debug: false,
  moreDebug: {},
  foo: {
    test: 'test',
    bar: function() {
      console.log(false)
    },
    moreTest: {
      weather: 'cool',
      say: function () {
        console.log('phew')
      }
    }
  }
}

const isObject = obj => typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null
const isFunction = func => typeof func === 'function'

function keepFunc(obj) {
  if (!isObject(obj)) {
    return null
  }
  if (Object.keys(obj).length === 0) {
    return null
  }


  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([key, value]) => [
        key,
        isFunction(value) ? value : keepFunc(value)
      ])
      .filter(([key, value]) => value !== null)
  )
}

console.log(keepFunc(obj))
```

**References**

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries): to transform object into key-value pairs

[Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries): to transform key-value pairs into object

Comment: This works wonders! However, it strangely keeps empty objects.

Comment: @Rivan you just need to add new base condition to check if the object is empty. I added that in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive function call in javascript to achieve that. For each key in the object check if it is an object or function and if it is keep it:

```js
var input = {
  helloWorld: function() {
    console.log("Test")
  },
  debug: false,
  foo: {
    test: "test",
    bar: function() {
      console.log(false)
    }
  }
};

function buildObjectsOnlyObject(obj) {
  let retVal = {};
  for (let key in obj) {
    const val = obj[key];
    if (typeof val === 'object') {
      if (!val) { // undefined and null also have object type
        continue;
      }
      if (val.__proto__ === Array.prototype) { // check if object is an array
        retVal[key] = val;
      } else {
        retVal[key] = buildObjectsOnlyObject(obj[key]);
      }
    } else if (typeof val === 'function') {
      retVal[key] = val;
    }
  }

  return retVal;
}

console.log(buildObjectsOnlyObject(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries` help here, as does `Array.prototype.some`.

For objects, filter the object's entries and keep only entries whose values are functions or objects with descendants that are functions.  This can be checked recursively.

Then let each value be either the function or the stripped nested object.

This `strip` function will return `undefined` if nothing is kept.

```js
let example =
{
  helloWorld: function () {
    console.log("Test")
  },
  debug: false,
  foo: {
    test: "test",
    bar: function () {
      console.log(false)
    }
  }
};

let isobj = val => typeof val == 'object' && val !== null;
let isfn = val => typeof val == 'function';
let keep = val => isobj(val) ? Object.entries(val).some(keepEntry) : isfn(val)
let keepEntry = ([key, val]) => keep(val);
let stripEntry = ([key, val]) => [key, strip(val)];
let strip = val => keep(val) ? isobj(val) ?
              Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(val).filter(keep).map(stripEntry)) :
              isfn(val) ? val : undefined : undefined


console.log(strip(example));
```

*(Surprisingly this took more code than I thought it would.)*